How can I prevent child forms in a C#/WinForms application to open maximized in tablet mode?
I have a Windows Forms application that opens child forms. The forms are opened by calling Form.ShowDialog().
When the application is being executed on a tablet PC with Windows 11 then the child form always opens in maximized mode. This is not what I want.
How can I prevent the child forms being opened in maximized mode?
I have written a small sample application:
namespace DialogSizeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This shows a dialog in "normal" size even on Panasonic Tablet with Windows 11.
            var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This shows a maximized dialog on Panasonic Tablet with Windows 11. Why?
            var dlg = new MyOwnDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}

MyOwnDialg() is just a very simple Windows Form with one label on it.
I have used that application to test on the following configurations:



Test#
Hardware
Windows Version
Main Form Size
File Open Size
My Own Dialog Size




1
Laptop
11
normal
normal
normal


2
Tablet PC
10 (tablet mode on)
maximized
normal
normal


3
Tablet PC
10 (tablet mode off)
normal
normal
normal


4
Tablet PC
11
maximized
normal
maximized



Tests 1,2,3 have the results that I would expect.
Test 4 has an unexpected result! I would expect my own dialog to be normal size.

You can override OnLoad() or OnShown() in the Forms that should open with WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal and change the WindowState if it's not what you expect. Call base first

Jimi's comment contained the answer to my question. Setting WindowState in OnLoad() of all my forms solves the problem:
private void MyOwnDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

(However I still wonder, why Windows 11 introduced such a strange behaviour in the first place.)
